# Is there a triplet paradox analogous to the twin paradox?

Tags: special-relativity

Assume a scenario like in the classical twin paradox. A and B start out on Earth with synced clocks. A stays put, B moves relativistically far away, then returns. As a result, B's clock shows less time has passed than A's, but they now again running at the same speed.

Now assume that at start, both observe C at some distance and note down C's clock.

A stays put, B travels far away and returns.

What do A and B think about C's clock though, if

- a) stays at rest relative to A the whole time
- b) moves at some constant speed in some arbitrary direction, not necessarily parallel or orthogonal to B's movement, or
- c) C moves arbitrarily including
  relativistically relevant accelerations during B's trip?

I would assume that A and B at their reunion will agree on what they see on C's clock - my question is if that is correct in all scenarios?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is that correct"? Do you mean "can A and B correctly calculate what C observes on C's clock"? If so, yes... indeed the whole point of relativity is that you can calculate A's, B's, and C's clock from any set of coordinates, although the calculation is much simpler if the coordinate system is moving inertially the whole time  (which presumably A is in this scenario.. B definitely is not, and C is in cases a and b).

Comment: What is stopping you from calculating this?

Comment: What have you tried till now ? show us what calculations you have tried to do ? How have you tried to approach this , and where are you getting stuck. Otherwise it is just like a homework question that you are asking others to solve for you

Comment: I have not tried to calculate anything, sorry. I'm not a student of physics, just an interested layman. I do have a background in math, but completely different areas than what'd be relevant here. I'm trying to get a better basic understanding of the consequences of relativity, nothing more..

Answer (score 2):

No.

The twins "conundrum" (I don't even want to call this FAQ a "paradox" any more!) is simply there to teach students that different paths through spacetime give different results in general.  There is *no more to be learned* by embellishing the idea with additional observers or other artifacts.  In practice, attempting this usually just adds to any existing confusion.

I will go further and speculate that most attempts to add to the scenario are motivated **entirely** by a lack of understanding of the [spacetime interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval).  If you do not understand this idea you should recognize that you not going to learn any more easily by making things more complicated!

Just learn about the spacetime interval, *draw a spacetime diagram*, and you will not *need* to ask about it here. If you do not understand the spacetime interval or know how to draw a [spacetime diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram) you will not understand the answers properly anyway.